# Nodeclise , Enide does not execute the cluster code on debug mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, nodeclipse, enide

I am using Eclipse Enide to build a nodejs application. I am able to run it all right and the web services are running.But while debugging I choose Debug As > Node Application . 
I see no error, the console shows debugger is running on port 5858 and 5859 (its a cluster). But the same web service endpoint gives the error as connection refused.

On debugging I see that the cluster code is never executed and the break is never hit.

```
const throng = require('throng');
var http_servers = [];

throng({
  workers: process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1,
  lifetime: Infinity
},mainServerCode);

function mainServerCode() {
  // require('newrelic');
  var express = require('express');  // this code is never hit
  ....
```

What could be the reason and where to check it.
Thanks